# Can Spring Boot embedded Tomcat access webapps folder of defined spring.tomcat.basedir

Tags: angular, apache, spring-boot, tomcat

Planning to deploy a Spring Boot JAR application using the embedded Tomcat. As seen on the `application.properties`, I have defined a few Tomcat parameters. My question is can I access the webapps folder of the base directory to serve front end elements using Angular as if I deployed the application as WAR? Access logs work as intended.

application.properties

```
server.tomcat.basedir=c:/servers/instances/app_dep/
server.tomcat.uri-encoding=UTF-8
server.tomcat.accesslog.directory=c:/servers/instances/app_dep/logs
server.tomcat.accesslog.enabled=true
```

Server Environment 
`Windows Server`
`Apache 2.4`
`Tomcat 9`

webapps path - `c:/servers/instances/app_dep/webapps/app_name`

I already configured `mod_jk` for Apache 2.4 thus I can access endpoints using `IP_ADDRESS/app_name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, embedded Tomcat as configured in Spring Boot does not watch the `webapps` folder and will not deploy a war file that is copied there.

If you want to serve static content from your Spring Boot application then one option is to package that content in your jar file. By default, anything in `src/main/resources/static` will be packaged in the jar file in a location that makes it accessible via HTTP. For example, a file named `src/main/resources/static/css/style.css` will be packaged in `BOOT-INF/classes/static/css/style.css` and will be accessible via HTTP at `/css/style.css`.